# Website Rendering Problem: Safari 4 displays flash of content, then white screen

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css, uri

I'm working on developing a [rails application](http://fairviewhs.org), and I'm getting word from Safari 4 users of a strange and irregular rendering error in which the page appears briefly, but quickly disappears and is replaced by a blank white page.

I have not been able to replicate the problem in Safari 5 on Lion, but I have encountered the problem a number of times on Safari 4 for iOS. Without access to Snow Leopard or Safari 4, I haven't been able to do any testing on that end.

Sometimes reloading the page allows the user to access the content, but sometimes it takes more than ten attempts before anything actually happens.

Also, in some instances, the page displays fine, but some partial HTML tags appear on the site. This may or may not be related, but I've only encountered the problem in iOS.

Right now my best guess is that the problem is being caused by some malfunction in the Data URI embedding of images or some other sort of scripting error, but beyond that I have no idea.

**Access the website here** — http://www.fairviewhs.org

from the the embedded ruby layout:

```
<head>
  <%= include_stylesheets :screen, :media => 'screen, projection' %>
  <%= include_stylesheets :print, :media => 'print' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "event_calendar", :media => 'screen, projection, print' %>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "compiled/ie", :media => 'screen, projection' %>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script src="<%= javascript_path "load" %>" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    head.js(
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js",
      "http://gettopup.com/releases/latest/top_up-min.js",
      "<%= javascript_path "rails" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "application" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "jquery.sap" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "sap" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "forms" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "nested_form" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "event_calendar" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" %>",
      "<%= javascript_path "midiswag" %>"
    );
  </script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag %>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <%- if @title.blank? -%>
    <title>Fairview High School</title>
  <%- else -%>
    <title>Fairview High School > <%= @title %></title>
  <%- end -%>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an old computer with Snow Leopard still on it—the problem was a scripting error in the file `http://gettopup.com/releases/latest/top_up-min.js`

I still have no idea why the problem occurred only in Safari 4/5 in Snow Leopard and iOS, but removing that line of code from the `<head>` certainly did the trick.